# Mobile version to Tablet version and iOS version

Tags: android, ios, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've made a mobile version of a specific app. But the next requirement now is to build an app that can be run from mobile OR tablet.

If my app supports the compatibility version in mobile from M to lower, will it run also to a tablet. (Given it is also an android tablet not an iOS)

**Next Question**

Also, i'm sure that the next requirement will be to develop for an iOS app.

do I need to work it again in iOS version or there is a certain way to convert or to do at once the android and iOS version?

thanks for advance

**just a quite beginner here in android dev and new to iOS and Tablet app development:)**

***C# - XAMARIN DEVELOPER**

Answer (score 0):

In Android if you are making app for Mobile Only and you want to support Tablet also then don't worry just add one folder that contains the Tablet layout file and set the layout compare to Tablet that you have to display.

IOS Development :

For Ios If you have to Create Only App for iPhone and you have support Tablet also.
  Then go to `Info.plist`. file and change Devices setting to `Universal`

that can support iPhone and iPad both.

If you have any doubt then free feel to ask.

Comment: regarding iOS, what I am planning to do is to work both on iOS and android at once, not for iOS only :)

it's either android phone -> with android tablet compatibility -> with iOS compatibility if possible

Comment: you can do to support `IOS` and `Android` both just do as you can support to do in only `Android` and `iOS`. But the thing you have make common backend for that so you have to take one project that is PCL(Portable Class Library).

Comment: thanks sir for that info :) I'll take note for that PCL :) Is there still other way to do this? I just want to take all options :) but noted for that PCL

Comment: If you create the PCL then you have to write your common Api call only one time.